# Android studio 3.0.1 fixedRateTimer

Tags: android, kotlin, таймер

Запускается таймер

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val fixedRateTimer_push = fixedRateTimer(name = "startPush", //false,
            initialDelay = 0, period = 7000, daemon = false) {

        println("timer-push-start!");
}
```

Таймер работает и старательно печатает с указанным повтором...

Добавляем показ изображения

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val fixedRateTimer_push = fixedRateTimer(name = "startPush", //false,
            initialDelay = 0, period = 7000, daemon = false) {

        println("timer-push-start!");


             val ros_view_1 = ImageView(this@MainActivity)
  //          val ros_view_1 = "ros_1";
        ros_view_1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ros_1);
        setContentView(R.layout.ros_view_1);
}
```

Таймер выводит изображение на экран, но только один раз, отладка
     останавливается, на симулятор выводится "Open app again", можно еще раз
     запустить и нормально пройдет еще раз с последующей остановкой, но
     планируемых повторов запуска таймера нет... Ошибок вроде нет, Logcat
     выдает вроде "внутренняя остановка"...